# Froala Font-Size Popup direction is wrong

Tags: javascript, css, froala

With Froala in an iFrame, how do I force the Font-Size and Font-Family popups to open DOWN (instead of UP, as seen in this pic)
[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the CSS code added below in the JSFiddle document.

```
.fr-command.fr-btn+.fr-dropdown-menu{
   bottom: auto !important;
    top: 39px!important;
}
.fr-command.fr-btn+.fr-dropdown-menu .fr-dropdown-wrapper .fr-dropdown-content {
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3aj9nc61/5/